# Sequence of GROUP BY fields affects MySQL query results

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am learning MySQL and following the exercises on a website with practice problems (not named, but it is question 81).  At issue is the sequence of the fields following GROUP BY.  I am certain the field sequence following GROUP BY affects the results of the query based on the reported comparison between the expected and actual number of rows from a hidden table.  My understanding from much reading on this site and others is it should not matter.

The task is:

```
 From Outcome table, retrieve all rows for that month (months) 
 in view of a year, in which total value of expenses (out) is maximal.
```

The table description is:

```
 Outcome(code, point, date, out) where code is the primary key, 
 point is a simple integer, date is in the format datetime, and out is a currency value.
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT code,point,date,`out` outc FROM outcome
    WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) =
        (SELECT mon bestmonth FROM 
            (SELECT MAX(sout), mon,yr FROM
                (SELECT SUM(outc) sout,mon,yr FROM
                    (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, `out` outc,
                         date,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr FROM outcome
                    ) maxmonth GROUP BY mon,yr
                ) peak
            ) tmonth
        ) 
    AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) =
        (SELECT yr bestyear FROM 
            (SELECT MAX(yout), mon,yr FROM
                (SELECT SUM(outy) yout,mon,yr FROM
                    (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, `out` outy,
                         date,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr FROM outcome
                    ) maxyear GROUP BY yr,mon
                ) peakb
            ) tyear
        )
```

While not an elegant query, I would like to understand why changing the order from 'GROUP BY mon,yr' to 'GROUP BY yr,mon' in the maxmonth and maxyear subqueries has any effect.

In the maxmonth subquery, 'GROUP BY mon,yr' results in:

```
Wrong  Your query produced correct result set on main database, 
but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (less by 6)
```

For the same maxmonth subquery, 'GROUP BY yr,mon' results in:

```
Wrong  Your query produced correct result set on main database, 
but it failed test on second, checking database
* Wrong number of records (less by 11)
```

Comment: That is a crazy query. Is that a translation of the original question 81?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that group by 1 columns doesn't means that all other columns will have the value of the grouped one..

For example, given the table:

```
 customer | value |  date
       1  |   2   | 2015-01-03
       1  |   3   | 2015-01-05
       2  |   3   | 2015-01-02
       2  |   4   | 2015-01-03
       2  |   5   | 2015-01-04
```

If you use

```
select customer, max(value), date from table group by customer
```

Your result may be

```
customer | max(value) |  date
      1  |      3     | 2015-01-03
      2  |      5     | 2015-01-02
```

Its not what you want... because the agregation functions works only for THAT column.

it coud help:

```
select year(date) yr, month(date) mon, sum(outc) totalOfMonth from outcome group by yr, mon order by totalOfMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` currently affects the order of the results returned (though MySQL has warned this behavior may change in the future, so to not rely upon it). Since the queries enclosing those GROUP BY queries have implied `GROUP BY` clauses that do not include non-aggregated fields, the values chosen to be returned for those fields is officially non-deterministic.

(It is usually the first or last value encountered, I avoid queries like these because of their unpredicatablity).

*Edit/FYI: Most other RDBMSes do not even allow queries with GROUP BY clauses that do not include all non-aggregated fields. That MySQL even allows it has been criticized; though it is my assumption the original intent (and server settings for more recent versions seem to confirm this) was to allow for more succinct queries where the query author KNOWS there will be only one set of values for non-aggregated fields per GROUPed set of values; such as when grouping by a primary key on one table and not including fields from joined tables that could vary (ex: only non-aggregated, non-grouped fields are from the table whose PK was part of the grouping criteria).*

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying.  To solve the issue, I removed the MAX and used a new subquery.  Unfortunately, the query tested on the website leads to a runtime error.  Would this (posted below due to comment limitations) have been a good workaround?  Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, my interpretation from the answers is to always use ALL relevant non-aggregate fields when using GROUP BY.  If there are additional fields in the table involved, there may be issues, and in this case, the MAX value may not be the true MAX value and may be arbitrary.  The original query included GROUP BY on the outcome table (maxmonth derived table) which did not include all non-aggregate fields and the results of the GROUP BY were suspect.

The main points from the answers as I understand is:

1) a query with an aggregate value such as MAX for a table should report the actual MAX value corresponding to the field value included in the GROUP BY clause (customer), but fields not included in the GROUP BY (such as date) will not necessarily correspond to the correct MAX value.  This is apparent from the first answer above where the customer and MAX value are correct, but the date (not included in GROUP BY) may not actually correspond to the customer / MAX value row.  Using a derived table (formattedOutMonthYear_sq  table) with only relevant non-aggregate values (month and year) and creating a new derived table (groupedOutMonthYear_sq table) to perform the aggregate SUM should result in the correct values for the month and year although code and point fields may not if the outcome table had been used instead of the formattedOutMonthYear table.

2) using an aggregate such as MAX (peak table) without explicitly including any GROUP BY for non-aggregated fields can lead to unexpected results.  In the original code, the aggregate MAX on a derived table including non-aggregates in a GROUP BY clause may still be clustered due to implicit grouping.

The GROUP BY still contains multiple columns but my interpretation from the answers above is that multiple columns are acceptable if ALL non-aggregate columns are included (Uueerdo) and additional fields are not to be extrapolated from the query (Renan).

Unfortunately, running the query results in a runtime error, which is unfortunate.  Thank you for explaining the results I observed and I will incorporate this logic into query writing.

```
SELECT o.code cd,o.point pnt ,o.date dt,`out` expense,mdt FROM outcome o
JOIN 
(SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mdt, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) ydt, code FROM outcome
) mnth
ON mnth.code = o.code
WHERE mdt =
    (
    SELECT distinct mon topMonth from 
        (SELECT SUM(outm) allOutMonth, mon, yr FROM 
            (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, `out` outm, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr 
            FROM outcome
            ) formattedOutMonthYear_sq GROUP BY yr, mon
        ) topMonth_sq 
        WHERE topMonth_sq.allOutMonth >= all
        (SELECT allOutMonth from
            (SELECT SUM(outm) allOutMonth, mon, yr FROM 
                (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, `out` outm,
                    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr 
                FROM outcome
                ) formattedOutMonthYear_sq GROUP BY yr, mon 
            ) groupedOutMonthYear_sq 
        )
    )        
AND ydt =
    (
    SELECT yr topTopYear from 
        (SELECT SUM(outm) allOutYear, mon, yr FROM 
            (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, `out` outm, 
                EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr 
            FROM outcome
            ) formattedOutYearMonth_sq GROUP BY yr, mon
        ) topYear_sq 
        WHERE topYear_sq.allOutYear >= all
        (SELECT allOutYear from
            (SELECT SUM(outm) allOutYear, mon, yr FROM 
                (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) mon, 
                    `out` outm, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) yr 
                FROM outcome
                ) formattedOutMonthYear_sq GROUP BY yr, mon 
            ) groupedOutYearMonth_sq 
        )
    )
```